# Is possible to create a lambda function dynamically?

Tags: c++, lambda

Now I create many lambda functions, and convert them to function ptr;

```
int (*fptr[5])() { nullptr };

fptr[1] = []()->int
{
    return 1;
};

fptr[2] = []()->int
{
    return 2;
};

fptr[3] = []()->int
{
    return 3;
};

fptr[4] = []()->int
{
    return 4;
};
```

But they are duplicate codes simple...

I want to create them just in a

```
for(int i=0;i<nums;i++) {
    //...
}
```

How to do that?
Or there are some alternative ways?

The number of function ptr is a constant.

Comment: Do they need to be regular function pointers, or would some other type be acceptable? And how portable does the solution need to be?

Comment: Lambdas, like functions, create machine language code. This is done by compilers. For loops are executed at runtime. You can't define a lambda at runtime.  However, template metaprogramming, which is compile time, may work depending on your specific needs.

Comment: Is `nums` a compile-time constant? Or is it a runtime value? If a compile-time constant, then you can do `[&]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) { ((fptr[I] = []{ return (int)I; }), ...); }(std::make_index_sequence<nums>{});`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use `std::function` in the STL to solve this problem, just like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    std::function<int(void)> arr[5];

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        arr[i] = [=](void){ return i;};
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout<< arr[i]() << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you compile and run the code above, you will see the output: `0 1 2 3 4` . This means that we've stored 5 lambdas in the array of `std::function<int(void)>`. If you change the number '5' to '10', you'll see 10 numbers were printed, and so on if the number is N, then you will store N lambdas in the array and see N numbers.

More broadly, you can use `std::function` not only on lambdas but also on function pointers, callable objects, etc. The effect is similar.

Comment: In some reasons , I want convent them to normal function pointers.But a lambda function with capture list can't do this..